# Sata RAID5 Orphan Drive

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid5

so today, one of our hadware RAID5-controllers (Sil3124 (r5), 4x 2TB) went into degraded / legacy mode without any notifications. Additionally, automatically rebuilding the raid-group failed:

[Event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrbFz.jpg)

The SATARAID5 Array Manager displays the controller to be a Legacy Group which cannot be accessed. Also, the array shows an orphan drive, see the following album (2 more images):

[Orphan Drive + Device summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Aaf.jpg)

Upon investigating the device summary, it doesn't seem to be a harddrive failure since all the disks show up as "Healthy".

The machine has been running a few years now (according to my former colleague) on Vista 64bit. I know that this RAID-setup is really terrible, please do not tell me about this as I did not set it up.

Thank you for your time and help in advance!

Edit: forgot the actual question: is there any chance to recover the data by recreating the array / swap disks?

Comment: Data is not lost, you need to replace drive 3 which had SCSI errors, and array will rebuild with new drive.

Comment: Hello Hrvoje, thank you for your suggestion. I have replaced the drive with a new (similar) one, but I still cannot access the drive(s). When booting into the BIOS menu of the raid card, it says "invalid raid". When using Windows, the raid is still displayed as "Legacy Raid" and the new drive is labelled "PASS-THRU".

Any advice? I am not sure whether the data will be erased when creating a new raid group.

Comment: Sadly I have zero experience with managing those things from windows. I'm not sure if this 'legacy RAID' means you can access data from windows? because degraded mode in RAID terms means it's simply not optimal, not that all data is lost. To resolve new drive pass-thru thing you would need to associate it with the 3 drive group and initiate array rebuild (probably from raid bios, or from some raid management utility in windows

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot access data from Windows. I have searched through half of Google but there is hardly any information about this *** controller. The controller won't let me rebuild the array nor can I add it to the legacy group in any way. I have read somwhere that recreating the array would work, though I think this would simply erase all the stored data on the disks, just like I think converting it to a "Legacy RAID Group" would do so, too.

Comment: Referring to XKCD #979 (http://xkcd.com/979/), I would like to explain what I did in order to rescue the seemingly lost data. I was not able to reconstruct the RAID or find any data on it on Windows. Using the linux distribution from runtime.org with the product "Raid Recovery for Windows", I could easily mount the drives and copy the data to an external drive. Phew!

Comment: excellent! I'm glad to hear you managed to get to your data!